# How can I render a list of checkboxes with checkboxes with django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I want to create this form with django;

```
[ ] parent_checkbox1  
  [ ] sub_cb1_pcb1  [ ] sub_cb2_pcb1
...
[ ] parent_checkbox10
  [ ] sub_cb1_pcb10  [ ] sub_cb2_pcb10
```

I can render the parent checkboxes with:

```
parent = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Parent",
                                       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
self.fields['parent'].choices = 'list of choices'
```

But how can I add the sub_checkboxes to the parent?

Comment: Have you considered custom field/widget - post here might help http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery dynatree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) plugin instead. I thought of writing a custom widget, but found this one much easier to install and maintain.

For that, you'll need to output a recursive HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
   <ul>
      <li id="1">Element 1</li>
      <li id="2">Element 2
          <ul> ... </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Install the js file and call a jquery method:

```
$('#tree').dynatree(parameters);
```

Comment: Interesting with a different solution, I guess you include div=tree in a form post,  but how would you handle it within django after submit?

Comment: I can't remember exactly whether it makes any hidden input. If no, yo can bind a callback and set some values, then receive a string and parse it. I used a callback to set cookies, because I didn't need a form.